# Incremental rename batch output before overwritten

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

I am using a basic command line program to convert .xml files to .csv. I have it performing the action on all .xml files in the directory using

```
FOR %I in (..\xmlinput\*.xml) DO XmlToCsv.Console.exe -xml %I -dir ..\csvoutput\
```

This works fine but all output files are named r.csv, so each time it loops the previous r.csv is overwritten. How can I incrementally rename the output (r1.csv, r2.csv, etc.) before the next loop runs and overwrites the previous output? (the XmlToCsv.Console.exe has no additional parameters to use). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a batch-file, you can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "counter=1"
FOR %%I in (..\xmlinput\*.xml) DO (
XmlToCsv.Console.exe -xml %%I -dir ..\csvoutput\
ren "..\csvoutput\r.csv" "r!counter!.csv"
set /a "counter+=1"
)
```

Note that because this is a batch-file and not a single command you need to use `%%I` instead of `%I`. You might also need to change the paths for the rename command.

Comment: you can also keep the filename, if you want: `ren "..\csvoutput\r.csv" "..\csvoutput\%%~nI.csv"`. @Dennis: `ren` does not suport a path for the destination: `ren "path\oldname.ext" "newname.ext"`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. By setting \xmlinput\ and \csvoutput\ as the same folder the %%~nI.csv option works well. Thanks.